# Kasus beim 'wie'

Tags: grammatical-case, idiomaticity

Ich habe in Thomas Bernhards Roman *Korrektur* das Folgende gesehen.

> An ihr hing Roithamer mit der ganzen Liebe, die einem Menschen wie er
> möglich ist ...

Meine Frage ist nun, ob das 'er' das einzige Idiomatische sei.  Wäre
es auch idiomatisch, stattdessen 'ihm' zu schreiben?  Man nähme also
kein 'wie er [ist]' an, ließ aber vielmehr das Pronomen mit dem
'Menschen' übereinstimmen.

Comment: **ihm** wäre sogar die korrekte Form.

Comment: My understanding is that with  *ein_ X wie Y*, as with most noun phrases, the entire thing gets the same case. So: *Ein Mensch wie ich liest.* *Sie kennen einen Menschen wie mich.* *Einem Menschen wie mir gefällt ein gutes Buch.* *Sie sind sich eines Menschen wie meiner bewusst.* (I'm not too sure about the last one.) The dative of *er* is *ihm* so I think @choXer is correct.

Comment: Bitte ergänze deine Angabe der Quelle durch Buchtitel und Ausgabe! in dieser Form könnte das alles auch einfach ausgedacht sein!

Comment: Möglicherweise lautete der Satz zuerst "... mit der ganzen Liebe, zu der ein Mensch wie er fähig ist..." und als der Autor das auf "...einem Menschen...möglich ist..." umgestellt hat, hat er verabsäumt, das "er" auf "ihm" zu ändern.

Comment: @Wolf: aus dem Roman "Korrektur". Google findet den Satz in Sekundärliteratur, wo er zitiert wird mit einem [sic] hinter dem "er".

Comment: @ammoQ SCNR: genau, *verabsäumt* ist okay, *vergessen* wäre wirklich schlimm gewesen ;)

Comment: @HalvarF Mein erster Impuls war derselbe, aber andererseits ist die Frage in diesem Punkt doch wirklich zu verwaschen.

Comment: @Wolf "verabsäumt" klingt doch viel netter als "vergessen" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Ich weiß nicht, ob ich das überhaupt als idiomatisch bezeichnen würde. Vielleicht gibt es andere, die beantworten können, ob es eine Mundart oder eine regionale Färbung gibt, in der man das so sagen würde wie Thomas Bernhard hier, mir ist keine bekannt. Für mich klingt das einfach falsch.

Hochdeutsch wäre, was du vorschlägst:

> die einem Menschen wie **ihm** möglich ist

Ohne den Text zu kennen, wäre denkbar, dass Bernhard hier eine künstliche Diktion erfindet, die den Sprecher in irgendeiner Weise charakterisieren soll, zum Beispiel als individualistisch und unkonventionell. Man müsste nachsehen, ob im Text noch weitere solche Beispiele von "schiefer" Sprache vorkommen.

Es kann natürlich auch schlicht und einfach ein Fehler sein.